# Synchronizing setting files cross computers

Tags: sync, cloud-storage

Many times we work on different computers but we want to have the same updated start-up and setting files available across.

We can obviously use cloud storage services but how do we update settings that are somewhere else on the computer (such as `C:\Program Files\`).

What kind of synchronization technique/program will you suggest for this?
For few programs I can use the portable versions and put them inside the cloud-storage folders but this is not a solution in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to start looking at roaming profiles.  Once I have that working, I would look at adding the users AppData directory into their profile.  This is where the majority of user-installed program settings are located.

If this is for personal use, this may be a little overkill, but in a corporate/enterprise environment, it would be trivial as it's all handled by group policies and other server functions that would already be in place.